# Logo as header using fancyhdr package

Tags: header-footer, positioning, fancyhdr

I want to use Logo as header in my document. However, I have not figured out how to use `fancyhdr` package efficiently. Text over wrap the header. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm, headheight=3pt, footskip=3pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{
\vspace*{-1.2cm}
\begin{center}
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=6cm]{LogoUAFMathStat.png}}
\end{center}
}


\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[25]

\end{document}
```

[image: LogoUAFMathStat.png is here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the known parameter, like the side margins first, then

```
\savebox\headbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo}}
```

With that savebox you can now calculate the header height and add some extra as that will be the effective top margin  with the `calc` package:

```
\setlength{\mytopmargin}{\totalheightof{\usebox\headbox} +1cm}
```

## Complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,calc,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,
          bmargin=2cm,
          lmargin=2cm,
          rmargin=2cm,
          footskip=3pt}
\newlength\mytopmargin
\newsavebox{\headbox}\savebox{\headbox}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{LogoUAFMathStat}}
\setlength{\mytopmargin}{\totalheightof{\usebox{\headbox}}+2cm}
\geometry{verbose,
          tmargin=\mytopmargin,
          headheight=1.1\mytopmargin}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\usebox\headbox}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[25]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Guilherme for your nice answer. Would appreciate if you guide me how to get fancy header on first page and after that without header. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Guilherme for your nice answer. Would appreciate if you guide me how to get fancy header on first page and after that without header with proper top alignment. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30228/custom-first-page-with-fancyhdr

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use `width` and `height` options in the `\includegraphics`  command at the same time.  It is sufficient, to use either one.  The other dimension will be scaled accordingly, without distortion.  If you use both, you have to take care to not ruin the proportions of your image. Or you can use the `keepaspectratio` option of `graphicx`, but the resulting image won't have the specified height *and* width, it will have the minimum dimensions to fit in a box of the specified height and width *without* distorcing the image proportions.

Unfortunately, I didn't have your logo file.  Hence I had to use a replacement file.  Nevertheless, I am sure, the problem can be found in the definition of the `\geometry`-command.  With regard to my logo, I was able to produce something usefull with `tmargin=7.5cm` and `headheight=8cm`.

Next, I changed your Fancyhead-definition as follows:

```
\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=6cm]{Logo}}
```

In total, the MWE could look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=7.5cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm, headheight=8cm, footskip=3pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=6cm]{Logo}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[25]
\end{document}
```

Have fun.

Comment: You are welcome @MYaseen208 . :-)

Comment: @Jan Do note that you can set both `width` *and* `height` **without** distorcing the image. Just pass the `keepaspectratio` option!

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli You are right.  You can use both `width` and `height` at the same time.  In those cases, it is very likely, that your image will ignore one of your arguments.  In this specific case, I would have only set one argument.  Either `\width=\linewidth` to stretch the image to the full line length, or  `\height=6cm`to scale it to a given height ...

Comment: @Jan, yes, true one Argument will be ignored (most of the times). But if you set both with `keepaspectratio` you don't have to worry where the Image is, it will always comply with the specifications. For instance, if your image is placed somewhere where `width=\linewidth` result in an `height<6cm` then you'll get a short Image and vice-versa.

Comment: @Jan, it makes sense: "You shouldn't use ***only*** width and height options in the \includegraphics command at the same time"